# Symfony - Checking something without method execution

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, event-handling, symfony4

In my Symfony project I have and idea to check for my entity field "created". When the creation date of that date is more into the past than two weeks I want to update that entity with some data.

As this is new functionality for me, I was planing to write a function that with DateTime object that will check that.

Other thing I wanted to ask is, how to do it without firing that specific method? Can it be checked regularly on page load or something like that?

What is the right approach here?

Is it an Event Listener the right thing or am I missing something else?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to prevent the usage of a specific method in function of a datetime right ? Please provide a sample of your model class

Comment: Actually what I want to accomplish is that is to check for every entity object  that if "created" field is persisted more than 14 days ago to update "status" field with 'expired' value. That is the thing I would know how to do. The problem is how to check and update id without firing specific method endpoint.. @Mcsky

Comment: What do you want to do if this field is more than 14 days ago? I'm trying to fully understand your problem to advise you the cleanest way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for that. To check which entity has datetime "created" filed older then two weeks and change it's status field from "active" to "expired". @Mcsky

Comment: Yes I understand that, which behaviour do you want to apply in each case? Return an error?

Comment: Just to check. If there is than update and if not skip (do nothing).. @Mcsky

Comment: If I understand , you can do it with a cronjob

Comment: Could be, I am just wondering are there any other alternatives? @hous

Comment: @joopeerr I don't know but you say " Can it be checked regularly on page load or something like that?" , no this not a good idea

Comment: in fact I worked with Symfony messenger to execute some operations asynchronously after some seconds or some minutes but not " two weeks", but if you want you can try.

Comment: I agree with @hous to do this in a cronjob.

Comment: I would not suggest to use symfony messenger as an 'extra'. Since @joopeerr doesn't want to visit a specific page, a cronjob should suffice, in which all operations are executed. Or use messenger as an 'extra' to dispatch updating the entity to a queue and let a new worker expire the entity.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [Symfony console commands](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html) / cronjobs.

1. You could schedule the command/cronjob to run once every day (or when you need it to).
2. In your console command you you could get all the articles that have a creation date and are older than your specified date. Use Doctrine Query Language (DQL) for this. I don't think you will need DateTime object for this. You can do it all in DQL
3. (Optional) If needed, you could dispatch an Event after an entity is updated (or put to expired), and build Listeners to do something extra.